# How do i insert a list into a SQLite database

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to insert a list into my SQLite database but it keeps coming up with `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "in":` syntax error.

The list generates fine but it just won't insert.

I am trying to get the list to show up in a single column in the table as
the smoking fox x 4
the chicken tinga torta x 2

Here's my code for inserting the list

```
order_list = []

for sandwich in order_details:
    if sandwich[0] == 1:
        order_list.append("The Smoking fox x " + str(sf))
    if sandwich[0] == 2:
        order_list.append("The Chicken Tinga Torta x " + str(ct))
    if sandwich[0] == 3:
        order_list.append("The Italo Disco Club x " + str(id))
    if sandwich[0] == 4:
        order_list.append("The Bomb x " + str(bo))
    if sandwich[0] == 5:
        order_list.append("Falafel burger  x " + str(fa))
    
print(order_list)

sql = """insert in orders (order,) values(?,)"""
cur.execute(sql, (order_list,))
con.commit()

flash("Order submitted")
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444155/python-proper-way-to-store-list-of-strings-in-sqlite3-or-mysql help?

Comment: not really, as im quite new to using python with sql and dont really understand the answers but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the link I provided you'll see a very simple answer from Joshua:
`'|'.join(list)`

You can translate that to work for you, with:

```
order_text = '|'.join(order_list)
sql = """insert into orders (order,) values(?,)"""
cur.execute(sql, (order_text,))
```

This will insert your list as text in a form like:

```
'The Smoking fox x 4|The Bomb x 1'
```

When you extract the order out of the database table you will need to split it on the `|` character

```
>>> order.split('|')
['The Smoking fox x 4', 'The Bomb x 1']
```

You have your list returned from the database.

In essence, convert the `list` into a delimited text string, insert into the database. To use it, extract from database, convert it back into a `list` via the `split` function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a typo

You need to use `INSERT INTO` not `INSERT IN`

Change `insert in orders (order,) values(?,)` into `insert into orders (order,) values(?,)`

---

Update:
Since `order` is a key word in sql,you need to escape it,maybe something as below

```
insert into orders (`order`) values(?)
```

You can have a try,since I am not very good at `sqlite`

Comment: now im getting this error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "order": syntax error

Comment: @jakobmja `order` is a key word in sql,you need to escape it or use a new column name

Comment: now im getting sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.