# Insert list into single sqlite database column

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a list of data that needs to be inserted into a single database column. I am getting this error when trying to do it:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.
```

That parameter is a list as follows:

> `['\r\n', ' \n', 'Please let me know if you still need Curve Shift.\n',
>   '\n', 'Thanks,\n', 'Heather\n', ' -----Original Message-----\n',
>   'From: \tAllen, Phillip K.  \n', 'Sent:\tFriday, December 07, 2001
>   5:14 AM\n', 'To:\tDunton, Heather\n', 'Subject:\tRE: West Position\n',
>   '\n', 'Heather,\n', '\n', 'Did you attach the file to this email?\n',
>   '\n', ' -----Original Message-----\n', ...`
>
> **(list continues)...**
>
> `'\n', 'Let me know if you have any
>   questions.\n', '\n', '\n', 'Heather']`

I extract part of a text file like so:

```
def extract_values(f):
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("X-FileName:"):
            data = lines[line_number:]  # read from specified line until end of file
            break
```

I'd prefer the data be inserted raw into the table so that it can be read out and enumerated line by line just like a text file. How do I do this? Should I use the `blob` type? How should I extract the data differently so it is inserted 'as is' without all the tab and newline codes?

Comment: pickle i.e. serialization [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: @AliGajani thanks, I am having a hard time finding an example related to sqlite, would I then use a blob column type?

Comment: If you want to store a pickled object, you'll need to use a blob, since it is binary data.

Comment: @AliGajani can you link to an example? I can find lots of examples of writing picked binary data to files, but not to database fields. [What I have found for sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/539636/4240919) doesn't use pickle at all and I'm not sure it can be easily retrieved and worked with (pickle seems better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). It is a Python module used to serialize an object and store it somewhere. If you are unaware of serialization, please read it [up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

In short, you convert a data object to binary, marshall it over a network, or store it in a database as a blob. You can then use it later on.

In your query, you can probably have your object pickled, store it in a variable such as `pdata`, and then put it in your desired blob column field like:

```
cursor.execute("YOUR SQL QUERY", sqlite3.Binary(pdata))
```

Also, I just saw that your list contains textual data, which can be converted to JSON and that way, you could easily do a JSON dump of your specified list into the sqllite3 column.

Comment: That's fine. Doesn't matter. I am here to help Bob. That matters :)

Comment: and I appreciate it very much