# Is it possible to store Python class objects in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, serialization

I would like to store Python objects into a [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database. Is that possible?

If so what would be some links / examples for it?

Comment: It may well be as easy as just pickling the object and storing it in a table. HOWEVER if that database is talking with the outside world pickle opens up a huge security whole because when we say it stores the object it *really* stores it. That opens gnarly options for hacks like putting malicious code into the store so it unpacks into a bomb (I have a story I'm honor bound not to tell about a famous MMO I cant name that once used pickles in its wire format. Players figured it out, fun occured. )

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can't store the object itself in the DB. What you do is to store the data from the object and reconstruct it later.

A good way is to use the excellent [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) library. It lets you map your defined class to a table in the database. Every mapped attribute will be stored, and can be used to reconstruct the object. Querying the database returns instances of your class.

With it you can use not only sqlite, but most databases - It currently also supports Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, MS-SQL, Firebird, MaxDB, MS Access, Sybase, Informix and IBM DB2. And you can have your user choose which one she wants to use, because you can basically switch between those databases without changing the code at all.

There are also a lot of cool features - like automatic `JOIN`s, polymorphing...

A quick, simple example you can run:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode, UnicodeText, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from random import choice
from string import letters

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/teste.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(40))
    address = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    password = Column(String(20))

    def __init__(self, name, address=None, password=None):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        if password is None:
            password = ''.join(choice(letters) for n in xrange(10))
        self.password = password

Base.metadata.create_all()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
# create instances of my user object
u = User('nosklo')
u.address = '66 Some Street #500'

u2 = User('lakshmipathi')
u2.password = 'ihtapimhskal'

# testing
s.add_all([u, u2])
s.commit()
```

That would run `INSERT` statements against the database.

```
# When you query the data back it returns instances of your class:

for user in s.query(User):
    print type(user), user.name, user.password
```

That query would run `SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.address AS users_address, users.password AS users_password`.

The printed result would be:

```
<class '__main__.User'> nosklo aBPDXlTPJs
<class '__main__.User'> lakshmipathi ihtapimhskal
```

So you're effectively storing your object into the database, the best way.

Comment: First,thank you all for your answers/guide/tips!!! and @ nosklo ,thanks you sample code worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot. I'll explore more about sqlalchemy with your example- Seems like that will suit my requirement..thanks you all again.

Comment: First,thank you all for your answers/guide/tips!!! and @ nosklo ,thanks you sample code worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot. I'll explore more about sqlalchemy with your example- Seems like that will suit my requirement more than pickle..thanks you all again.

Comment: Yeah, IMHO `pickle` is **not** worth it. It seems cool and all, but you **can't** filter/join/agreggate data since the object is stored as a *blob*, defeating the purpose of using a database in first place.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I think pick works only for object which need no searching.

Comment: yes,I need to perform search on data ..so pickle won't help me there...but sqlalchemy seems like the perfect candidate.

Comment: @nosklo Can I use this technique to store dictionary (specifically a result from locals() ) in a database?

Answer (score 24):

Yes it's possible but there are different approaches and which one is the suitable one, will depend on your requirements.

- **Pickling**

  You can use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module to serialize objects, then store these objects in a   blob in sqlite3 (or a textfield, if the dump is e.g. base64 encoded). Be aware of some possible problems: [questions/198692/can-i-pickle-a-python-dictionary-into-a-sqlite3-text-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198692/can-i-pickle-a-python-dictionary-into-a-sqlite3-text-field)
- **Object-Relational-Mapping**

  You can use object relational mapping. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that can be used from within the programming language ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)). For python, there is a nice toolkit for that: [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Answer (score 16):

You can use [pickle.dumps](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), its return pickable objects as strings, you would not need to write it to temporary files.

> Return the pickled representation of
>   the object as a **string**, instead of
>   writing it to a file.

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    attr = 'a class attr'

picklestring = pickle.dumps(Foo)
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, tbh. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 13):

## SQLite 3's adaptors and converters

I'm surprised by how *no one* has read the **docs** for the SQLite 3 library, because it says that you can do this by creating an adaptor and converter. For example, let's say that we have a class called '`Point`' and we want to store this and have this returned when selecting it and using the database cursor's `fetchone` method to return it. Let's make the module know that what you select from the database is a point

```
from sqlite3 import connect, register_adaptor, register_converter

class Point:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y
def __repr__(self):
    return "(%f;%f)" % (self.x, self.y)

def adapt_point(point):
    return ("%f;%f" % (point.x, point.y)).encode('ascii')

def convert_point(s):
    x, y = list(map(float, s.split(b";")))
    return Point(x, y)

# Register the adapter
register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)

# Register the converter
register_converter("point", convert_point)

p = Point(4.0, -3.2)

# 1) Using declared types
con = connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
con.execute("create table test(p point)")
con.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
cur = con.execute("select p from test")
print("with declared types:", cur.fetchone()[0])
con.close()

# 1) Using column names
con = connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
con.execute("create table test(p)")
con.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
cur = con.execute('select p as "p [point]" from test')
print("with column names:", cur.fetchone()[0])
con.close()
```

Comment: Reading the docs is next-level! [Here's a link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe docs in general should suck ass less then and be more educational instead of "To understand each article you need to know everything there is to know about our product, except for the article you're reading". Because that's definitely my experience with all the docs I've read: MSDN, cppreference.com, python documentation, etc. Like, there's little sense in reading MSDN if you don't know C++ and system programming, little sense in reading cppreference if you're not a kick-butt C++ developer which knows a lot about the language, etc.

Comment: Any advise on what the Python class `Point` needs to look like to have the sqllite table `create table test(p)` created with a new PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT column called `id`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to serialize the object. The serialized object can be inserted to the sqlite DB as a bytearray field.

```
f=open('object.dump', 'rw')
pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

Now read `object.dump` from the file, and write it to the sqlite DB. You might want to write it as a binary data type; read about storing binary data and blob in SQLite [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/252531/). Note that according to [this source](http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm), SQLite limits the size of such datafield to 1Mb.

I think that a better option would be serializing your object into a file, and keeping the file *name*, not contents, in the database.

Comment: This is far from good practise. Storing pickled objects as blobs in a database subverts the reasoning for using a database, searchability. storing the filenames in the database because of file size restrictions does not make this any better.

Answer (score 1):

You other choice instead of pickling is to use an **ORM**. This lets you map rows in a database to an object. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/HigherLevelDatabaseProgramming for a starting point. I'd recommend [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There is relatively simple way to store and compare objects, eaven to index those objects right way and  to restrict (with ubique) columns containing objects. And all of that without using ORM engines. Objects mast be stored using pickle dump (so performance might be a issue) Here is example for storing python tuples, indexing restricting and comparing. This method can be easily applied to any other python class. All that is needed is explained in python sqlite3 documentation (somebody already posted the link). Anyway here it is all put together in the following example:

```
import sqlite3
import pickle

def adapt_tuple(tuple):
    return pickle.dumps(tuple)    

sqlite3.register_adapter(tuple, adapt_tuple)    #cannot use pickle.dumps directly because of inadequate argument signature 
sqlite3.register_converter("tuple", pickle.loads)

def collate_tuple(string1, string2):
    return cmp(pickle.loads(string1), pickle.loads(string2))

# 1) Using declared types
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

con.create_collation("cmptuple", collate_tuple)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table test(p tuple unique collate cmptuple) ")
cur.execute("create index tuple_collated_index on test(p collate cmptuple)")


######################### Test ########################

cur.execute("select name, type  from sqlite_master") # where type = 'table'")
print(cur.fetchall())

p = (1,2,3)
p1 = (1,2)

cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p1,))
cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", ((10, 1),))
cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (tuple((9, 33)) ,))
cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (((9, 5), 33) ,))

try:
    cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (tuple((9, 33)) ,))
except Exception as e:
    print e

cur.execute("select p from test order by p")
print "\nwith declared types and default collate on column:"
for raw in cur:
    print raw

cur.execute("select p from test order by p collate cmptuple")
print "\nwith declared types collate:"
for raw in cur:
    print raw

con.create_function('pycmp', 2, cmp)

print "\nselect grater than using cmp function:"
cur.execute("select p from test where pycmp(p,?) >= 0", ((10, ),) )
for raw in cur:
    print raw

cur.execute("select p from test where pycmp(p,?) >= 0", ((3,)))
for raw in cur:
    print raw 

print "\nselect grater than using collate:"
cur.execute("select p from test where p > ?", ((10,),) )
for raw in cur:
    print raw  

cur.execute("explain query plan select p from test where p > ?", ((3,)))
for raw in cur:
    print raw

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs, it could be worth looking into Django (www.djangoproject.com) for this task. Django is actually a web framework, but one of the tasks it handles is to allow you to define Models as python objects (inheriting from a base class provided by the framework). It will then automatically create the database tables required to store those objects, and sqlite is among the supported backends. It also provides handy functions to query the database and return one or more matching objects. See for example the documentation about Models in django:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/

The drawback is of course that you have to install a full web framework, and (as far as I remember) you can only store objects whose attributes are supported by django. Also, it's made for storing many instances of predefined objects, not for storing one instance each of many different objects. Depending on your needs, this may or may not be impractical.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an O/R mapper like [SQLObject.](http://sqlobject.org/)  It will do most of the plumbing to persist the Python object to a database, and it supports SQLite.  As mentioned elsewhere you can also serialise the object using a method such as pickle, which dumps out a representation of the object that it can reconstruct by reading back in and parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the answer is yes... but the object needs to be serialized first.  I'm the author of a package called `klepto` that is built to seamlessly store python objects in SQL databases, HDF archives, and other types of key-value stores.

It provides a simple dictionary interface, like this:

```
>>> from klepto.archives import sqltable_archive as sql_archive
>>> d = sql_archive(cached=False)
>>> d['a'] = 1  
>>> d['b'] = '1'
>>> d['c'] = min
>>> squared = lambda x:x*x
>>> d['d'] = squared
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...   def __call__(self):
...     return squared(self.x)
... 
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> d['e'] = Foo
>>> d['f'] = f
>>> 
>>> d
sqltable_archive('sqlite:///:memory:?table=memo' {'a': 1, 'b': '1', 'c': <built-in function min>, 'd': <function <lambda> at 0x10f631268>, 'e': <class '__main__.Foo'>, 'f': <__main__.Foo object at 0x10f63d908>}, cached=False)
>>> 
>>> # min(squared(2), 1)
>>> d['c'](d['f'](), d['a'])
1
>>>
```

The `cached` keyword in the archive constructor signifies whether you want to use a local memory cache, with the archive set as the cache backend (`cached=True`) or just use the archive directly (`cached=False`). Under the covers, it can use `pickle`, `json`, `dill`, or other serializers to pickle the objects. Looking at the archive's internals, you can see it's leveraging `SQLAlchemy`:

```
>>> d._engine  
Engine(sqlite://)
>>> d.__state__
{'serialized': True, 'root': 'sqlite:///:memory:', 'id': Table('memo', MetaData(bind=None), Column('Kkey', String(length=255), table=<memo>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('Kval', PickleType(), table=<memo>), schema=None), 'protocol': 3, 'config': {}}
```