# How to run Flask-Login, Flask-BrowserID and Flask-SQLAlchemy in harmony?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, browserid

**The Whole Point**

I am attempting to make a fairly basic website with Flask (noob!) and am running into trouble with the user login system. I've decided that I want to use Flask-Login, Flask-BrowserID (Mozilla Persona) and SQLAlchemy. I am going to have Persona be the part that takes care of storing user passwords and such, I am going to use Flask-Login once the user has been authenticated to keep track of their sessions and I am going to use SQLAlchemy to store everything in an sqlite3 db. I've done a lot of bouncing around and I think I have almost finished these features, but I cannot seem to get back a specific error.

**Update 1**

Based on the comment by davidism, I had to add db.Model to the User class. Unfortunately, that solved the first error, but now there is a new one to deal with. Traceback found below.

**The Question**

What gives? I am obviously missing something, but I cannot seem to find what that is.

**Resources I have been working with**

- Flask-BrowserID: https://github.com/garbados/flask-browserid/wiki
- Flask-Login: http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- Flask-SQLAlchemy: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application
- [Is it possible to store Python class objects in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047814/is-it-possible-to-store-python-class-objects-in-sqlite)
- SQLAlchemy Docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html
- WORKING Flask-BrowserID: [https://github.com/garbados/flask-browserid/blob/master/tests/**init**.py](https://github.com/garbados/flask-browserid/blob/master/tests/__init__.py)

**Additional Information**

Here is my main.py and index.html I am using with Flask and the Traceback I am getting:

**MAIN.py**

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
from contextlib import closing
import time
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin
from flaskext.browserid import BrowserID
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

## SETUP
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/flaskr.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config['BROWSERID_LOGIN_URL'] = "/login"
app.config['BROWSERID_LOGOUT_URL'] = "/logout"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "deterministic"
app.config['TESTING'] = True

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, unique=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.Unicode(40))
    lastname = db.Column(db.Unicode(40))
    date_register = db.Column(db.Integer)
    bio = db.Column(db.Text)
    facebook = db.Column(db.Unicode(1000))
    twitter = db.Column(db.Unicode(1000))
    website = db.Column(db.Unicode(1000))
    image = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    def __init__(self, email, firstname=None, lastname=None, date_register=None, bio=None, facebook=None, twitter=None, 
                    website=None, image=None):
        self.email = email
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.date_register = time.time()
        self.bio = bio
        self.facebook = facebook
        self.twitter = twitter
        self.website = website
        self.image = image
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.email

### Login Functions ###
def get_user_by_id(id):
    """
    Given a unicode ID, returns the user that matches it.
    """
    for row in db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == id):
        if row is not None:
            return row.User
    return None

def create_browserid_user(kwargs):
    """
    Takes browserid response and creates a user.
    """
    if kwargs['status'] == 'okay':
        user = User(kwargs['email'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return user
    else:
        return None

def get_user(kwargs):
    """
    Given the response from BrowserID, finds or creates a user.
    If a user can neither be found nor created, returns None.
    """
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    # try to find the user
    for row in db.session.query(User).filter(User.email == kwargs.get('email')):
        if row is not None:
            return row.User
    for row in db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == kwargs.get('id')):
        if row is not None:
            return row.User
    # try to create the user
    return create_browserid_user(kwargs)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.user_loader(get_user_by_id)
login_manager.init_app(app)

browserid = BrowserID()
browserid.user_loader(get_user)
browserid.init_app(app)

### Routing ###
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**INDEX.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://login.persona.org/include.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">{{ auth_script|safe }}</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
            <button id="browserid-logout">Logout</button>
        {% else %}        
            <button id="browserid-login">Login</button>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/jzeller/Classes/CS494/main.py", line 106, in home
    return render_template('test.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 123, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 692, in update_template_context
    context.update(func())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 799, in _user_context_processor
    return dict(current_user=_get_user())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 768, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 348, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 312, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/Users/jzeller/Classes/CS494/main.py", line 60, in get_user_by_id
    print "get_user_by_id - " + str(type(row.User)) + " - " + str(row.User)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'User'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer to original question

The `User` model needs to be a subclass of `db.Model` (or a mapped class) to work with SQLAlchemy.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    ...
```

#### Answer to first update

You don't seem to understand what is getting returned by session.query.  If you query a single model, the "rows" that are returned are instances of the model.  The rows will never be None.  When you're checking for existence, you should just use `.first()` if you are applying filters, or `.get(primary_key)` if you are filtering by primary key.  This gets the first result only since the users are unique anyway

This is what your `get_user_by_id` should look like:

```
def get_user_by_id(id):
    return User.query.get(id)
```

This is what your `get_user` should look like:

```
def get_user(kwargs):
    u = User.query.filter(db.or_(
        User.id == kwargs.get('id'),
        User.email == kwargs.get('email')
    )).first()
    if u is None: # user didn't exist in db
        return create_browserid_user(kwargs)
    return u
```